# How to prevent default back button Apachhe Cordova?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I am currently in the making of an app using html, css and javascript but I've hit a dead end. I want to disable the default behavior of the back button on android devices, but all of my efforts have been in vein... I have read all the other questions here on Stack Overflow and on Apache Cordova, but whenever i debug the app on my own personal device, the back button does its' default behavior.

```
// In the initialization ...
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReadyHandler, false);


function deviceReadyHandler () {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButtonHandler, false);
}


function backButtonHandler(e) {
    //Here implement the back button handler
}
```

This is just a code snippet that most of the other questions is based upon, but sadly, it does not work for me. Can anyone help me please? If possible, can it be kept at pure vanilla JS? If I have to implement jQuery or some other plugin, I will, but I do not prefer it.

Comment: you want to stop quitting app on back button or stop moving back pages ?

Comment: I want to stop moving back pages and then on my home page i want a confirm prompt to show up when pressing the back button.